# C# Image.FromFile and Save on DB Size difference

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# program that reads from a JPG file and writes to my SQL Server database.

This is my piece of code:

```
string cSQL =
    "INSERT INTO xxx (ID, Image) " +
    "VALUES (@ID, @Image) ";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("xxx"))
{
    Image image = Image.FromFile(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}.jpg", source, ID));

    SqlParameter[] parametros = new SqlParameter[] {
        new SqlParameter("@ID", ID),
        new SqlParameter("@Image", ImageToByteArray(img))
    };

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cSQL, conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parametros);
    return  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
}
```

---

```
public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image image)
{
    if (image == null) return null;

    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(mStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] ret = mStream.ToArray();
    mStream.Close();
    return ret;
}
```

This code is working well, but the problem is the size of the field in my database.

For example, here is the comparative of the size of the varbinary(max) in my db and the size in kb of the jpeg images:

[image]

As you can see, the size of file and the size of my varbinary(max) field is soo different!

Am I doing anything wrong ?

PS: I'm using SQL Server DALENGTH(Image) function to get the size of the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saving the decoded `Image` to a `MemoryStream` and compressing it back to a JPEG, but perhaps the quality settings are different than what they were originally saved with.  More importantly, you're compressing the image twice; it's not going to compress well the second time around.  That also lowers the quality of the image.

Don't read it into an `Image` first.  It's a complete waste of cycles to read it, decompress it, and then compress it again (not to mention the quality loss).  Just read the binary stream of the file directly into the DB.

Comment: Could you please put an example of how I would change my code ?

Comment: Well, you're already doing most of the work.  Read the file into a stream and use a `BinaryReader` to get the bytes out.  Send the output to an array and you're done.

Comment: thanks for your help. Now it's working well. Here is the code I've used:

Comment: public static byte[] FileToByteArray(string arquivo)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(arquivo ,FileMode.Open))
            {
                    byte[] data = new BinaryReader(fs).ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
                    return data;
            }
        }